# WP7 autocomplete with a binding to search and a binding to show

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding, autocomplete

I have a problem with autocomplete textbox in WP7.
For now i have managed to make it possible to search for a customer by 'Title' which will then show options with 'Title' and 'Address'. But how do i show both bindings in the autocomplete textbox? I can show both of them as options in my datatemplate, but when i choose on it will only show the binding which are ValueMemberBinding.

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="acBox" ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" ItemsSource="{Binding Address}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,126,0,436" Width="420" Height="72">
            <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
                Foreground="#ff666666"
                 Text="{Binding Address}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Comment: can you share the code of codebehind?
What are you binding ItemsSource with?

Comment: It a WCF service that i use as itemssource for the textbox 
var results = e.Result;
            this.acBox.ItemsSource = results.OrderByDescending(a => a.Title);

It the above it difficult can i then show both bindings in the textbox? and how to do?


Which are sorted and contains Title, address, etc.